# How do I log into my child's OS X account (under parental control) without knowing the password?

Tags: macos, login, parental-controls

My child (single-digit age) and I share the same Mac Mini. She has an account under parental control. However, she doesn't want to give me her password.

How can I log into her account? Both from (1) she is not logged on; or (2) she is logged on but locked the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: I am using OSX 10.8.5

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by logging into her account? With an administrator account you can access all the files in her account without knowing or changing her password. You can also reset her password to a value you know, but then her password would be changed.

Comment: I need to use one of her apps (tv recorder). This app cannot be shared by two users so I let her run it.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can reset her password.

From a privacy point of view, you have to be clear with your policy. If you let her have an account with her own password, you implicitly agree that you should not log into her account without her approval. The solution is then to ask her to type her password so that you can use her account.